# mongodb aggregation: concatenate _id.day, _id,month, _id.year in output

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have following mongodb aggregation:

```
{
    "collection":"weather",
    "aggregate":[
        {
            "$match": {
                "site_id": 47,
                "timestamp": {
                    "$gte":{"$humanTime": "{{ date }}"} 
                } 
            }
        },
        {
        "$project": {
            "date": {"day": {"$dayOfMonth": "$timestamp"}, "month": {"$month": "$timestamp"}, "year": {"$year": "$timestamp"}}, 
            "temperature": "$temperature"
        }
        },
        {
        "$group":
         {
           "_id": "$date",
           "average_temp": {"$avg": "$temperature"}, 
            "max_temp": {"$max": "$temperature"}, 
            "min_temp": {"$min": "$temperature"}
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

which gives me following output:
[image]

I don't want the date like that. I want one column "date" with the date as dd-mm-yyyy. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you paste the output as code instead of image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the structure of your `_id` before returning the results using [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) and [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/)

```
{
    "collection":"weather",
    "aggregate":[
        {
            "$match": {
                "site_id": 47,
                "timestamp": {
                    "$gte":{"$humanTime": "{{ date }}"}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "date": {"day": {"$dayOfMonth": "$timestamp"}, "month": {"$month": "$timestamp"}, "year": {"$year": "$timestamp"}},
                "temperature": "$temperature"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group":
                {
                    "_id": "$date",
                    "average_temp": {"$avg": "$temperature"},
                    "max_temp": {"$max": "$temperature"},
                    "min_temp": {"$min": "$temperature"}
                }
        },
        {
            "$addFields" :{
                "_id": {
                    "$concat": [
                        {"$toString": "$_id.day"},
                        "/",
                        {"$toString": "$_id.month"},
                        "/",
                        {"$toString": "$_id.year"},
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: small extra question
I now got following format: 2020-4-7
how can I transform it to something like 2020-04-07 00:00

Comment: You can add `$toDate` to wrap the `_id` expression in the last `$addFields` stage.

Comment: yeah tried to do it like that, but that gives error

Comment: "$addFields": {
                "convertedDate": { "$toDate": {
                    "$concat": [
                        {"$toString": "$_id.day"},
                        "/",
                        {"$toString": "$_id.month"},
                        "/",
                        {"$toString": "$_id.year"}
                    ]
                } }
            }

Comment: What is the error, there should not be a problem: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YJjtIcMq3PQ